# Guidelines on structuring code for .net projects

Tags: asp.net, .net, coding-style

I generally use IoC pattern in my projects which are most of the time ASP.net based. Are there any guidelines on how to structure the projects in a general 3 layered project UI+BL+Data Access. I want to know more about how the folders should be created, where should constants be kept at within each layer (I keep all the strings such as query string parameters, stored procedure parameter etc in file named Constants which is singleton). How should I create classes that interact with Data Access layer from Business Layer etc. and all such code structure questions.

Is there any guidance or a book on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has a plethora of information on this.  I've used Microsoft .NET: Architecting Applications for the Enterprise as my bible for software architecture

[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft%C2%AE-NET-Architecting-Applications-Pro-Developer/dp/073562609X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073562609X)

Check out this MSDN guide as well

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647095.aspx

Also, take a look at some application frameworks like Sharp Architecture for examples

http://sharparchitecture.net/

A lot of NHibernate tutorials demonstrate software design principles that can be applied to any solution

http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2010/04/25/first-three-nhibernate-quickstart-tutorials-available.aspx

Answer (score 0):

@robbymurphy has a great answer.  I would only add that I keep most constants and interfaces in a separate project/assembly altogether.  I call this my "core" assembly and and define interfaces that allow me to pass data from the top of the stack to the bottom without tightly coupling them.

It is not so much where they are used, but for what purose.  I once attended a seminar class where the instructor pounded "high cohesion, low coupling" into our heads, over and over.

Keep those things that, in the real world, belong together, together, but, reduce dependencies between object whenever possible.

This is a cohesion question as well as a coupling issue: if the constants are truly internal to a class, make them private static members (i.e. and internal state enum) .  If they are truly internal to a project, create a class for them, and make them internal (a database specific constant in your data layer).  Otherwise, put them in a public class in their own project.

Comment: Hey is keeping all the constants in a separate project a good design? Doesn't it affect the scoping rules because you would need to make everything public and lookup time would be higher because its in a different assembly.

Comment: Certainly the scoping issue is a concern, but what is the alternative, if you want to share a resource (enum, interface, et cetera) across multiple projects?  As for performance, I would love to see/make some tests around the issue, to see how .net caches types and such between assemblies.  I very much doubt that, in 99% of the cases, performance would preclude this approach.

Comment: I agree keeping global constants in a separate project altogether is essential, but what about constants that are needed in say one or two classes in the same project. What should their ideal location be, should I create a folder named constants and stuff all the constants there?

Comment: It is not so much where they are used, but for what purose.  I once attended a seminar class where the instructor pounded "high cohesion, low coupling" into our heads, over and over.